# Getting a window's PID by clicking on it

Tags: xorg, process-management

Is there any package which shows PID of a window by clicking on it?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Yes. Try `xprop` and you are looking for the value of `_NET_WM_PID`:

```
xprop _NET_WM_PID | cut -d' ' -f3
{click on window}
```

Comment: Note that this information is provided voluntarily by the client and need not be correct, present or meaningful (remote clients, clients in a separate PID namespace).

Answer (score 24):

[`xprop`](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xprop.1.html) will return a window's PID.

You can filter the verbose output using `awk`:

```
xprop | awk '/PID/ {print $3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete those excellent answers, here is a little bash command to get the command (that I actually needed):

```
id=`xprop _NET_WM_PID | awk '/PID/ {print $3}'`; cat /proc/$id/comm
```

Example:

```
Lila ~ # id=`xprop _NET_WM_PID | awk '/PID/ {print $3}'`; cat /proc/$id/comm
```

gnome-terminal-